# Unable to get a local notification for NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, notifications, locale

I have implemented the following sample code to test if i can receive a notification for locale change(In my case, I need to get a notification when I change the language). But when I change the language and come back to the app, I am not getting the log statement which I have given. Is it the way to get the notification? If yes, what might be the reason for not getting the log displayed.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(notify:) 
                                  name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification 
                                  object:nil];
}

-(void)notify:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"Notification observed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If user change language, iOS restarts your application.
You can get this notification if user change current calendar or other components of current locale.